# How to change table cell background in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell

I have such table in HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to change cell's background on mouse move in this cell? If cursor moves away from the cell, background must stay, but if the cursor move to the other cell, it must reset background.

Comment: What exactly is your question about - the JS part, the CSS part...? At the moment, this looks like a "write the full code for me" type question.

Comment: Is a framework available? (jquery, prototype, mootools etc)

Comment: Frameworks is not used. It would be great if I could only use css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you need one cell highlighted, if you're including jQuery you could use this code.

```
(function() {

   var current_cell;

   $('td').bind('mouseenter', function() {
      if (current_cell) {
         current_cell.removeAttr('id');
      };
      current_cell = $(this);
      current_cell.attr('id', 'highlight');
   });
})();
```

and then just use a bit of css

```
td#highlight {
  background: ... ;
}
```